# insert select values into postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

i am trying to insert a date value in numeric datatype column of postgres table

```
insert into table tablename(col1) values(2017-09-25);
```

In the above query col1 is of type numeric.

Also can I insert some of the values using value() clause and some using the select statement? for example:

```
create tableA(col1 serial,col2 bigint,col3 bigint,col4 text,col5 boolean);
```

In the above table:
1. col1 is coming sequence
2. col2 and col3 are coming from the join of two tables i.e. tableB and tableC
3. col4 and col5 are the hard-coded value

how can i achieve this in a single query?

for insertion with the join of two tables can be achieved as follows:

```
insert into table(col2,col3) 
select tableB.col2,tableC.col3 
from tableB, tableC 
where tableB.id=1 and tableC.id=3;
```

so the output wil be like:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 
1     1    3
```

now how to insert the values of col4 and col5 also with the values of col2 and col3?

anyone any idea?

I am not able to find it.

Comment: please divide the question to individual posts with clear data sample, error and question

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table(col2, col3, col4, col5) 
select tableB.col2, tableC.col3, 'some text', true
from tableB, tableC 
where tableB.id=1 and tableC.id=3;
```